# Input doesn't add a value to a FORM when it is added by .html function

Tags: jquery

TEXT input is appearing in the form VISUALLY, but the value is not added to the FORM? only "somefield" has been added. Maybe I should bind it additionally?

```
<form action="/" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="somefield" value="somevalue">
<div class="addfield"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addfield').html('<input type="text" name="TEXT" value="SOME">');
});
</script>

//jquery:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear and hard to understand. Can you describe what output do you expect?

Comment: @reporter than you! I have updated a little bit! Basically with jquery added field value is not included in form values!

Comment: Check the console for errors. You need to make sure you include jQuery.js *before* you include your own jQuery code, assuming this isn't just an error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your jquery cdn link before to your jquery code. So first do this:

```html
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="somefield" value="somevalue">
<div class="addfield"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addfield').html('<input type="text" name="TEXT" value="SOME">');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are right. Everything works. Some mystic appears in my code. I'm going to clean it until it will be as simple as this to find an error...